# Tidy up bash script

Tags: bash, tidy

How can I tidy up the following bash script

```
tablename=$(echo "SELECT settings_table FROM prayertime_table where id = 1" | mysql prayertime -u root -pxxxxx)
vars=( $tablename)
myname=$(echo "select device_name from ${vars[1]}" | mysql prayertime -u root -pxxxxx)
data1=$(echo $myname | cut -d' ' -f2-)
```

Comment: What does "tidy up" mean? How do you differentiate a script that has been "tidied up" from a script that hasn't been "tidied up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean, how to write it in a more compact way.

Unless you need `tablename` again later on, this variable is not necessary:

```
vars=( $(mysql prayertime -u root -pxxxxx <<<"SELECT settings_table FROM prayertime_table where id = 1") )
```

The same applies to `myname`:

```
data1=$(cut -d' ' -f2- <<<$(mysql prayertime -u root -pxxxxx <<<"select device_name from ${vars[1]}"))
```

This assumes that you are happy with the functionality of your present script. If I would write such a script, I would however leave the `mysql` calls separately and evaluate the exit code, for the case that the `SELECT` results in an error.

Comment: Thanks. I only need the data1 how would you write this to evaluate the exit code please

Comment: I guess you mean the exit code of mysql. In this case, I would store the stdout of `mysql` into a variable and then evaluate `$?`, or, if you just need to distinguish zero and non-zero exit code, do it in a single `if vars=( $(mysql ...) ); then .....`.